# Как в Laravel показать в view, image из local storage?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть *jpeg*  в **local** ***storage*** файле `storage/app/MyFyle/1.jpg`

*Как показать* **1.jpg** файл ***из*** **local storage**,  на странице view:

Comment: Заданные __вам__ задачи никто здесь не собирается выполнять.

Comment: Если не хотите помочь, тогда,   что вы  **здесь** делаете .

Comment: Если вы не умеете гуглить - зачем вам доступ в интернет?

Comment: Если я здесь значит уже искал в интернете,  как понял помогать вы не собираетесь

Comment: *Перенёс ссылку в комментарий* - https://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2015-securing-filesimages